# Poll questions for members?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Because so many political questions are a matter of opinion, it would be excellent to add poll questions that members could vote on.  Is this planned?

Comment: No, we do not plan to allow pool questions any time soon.

Comment: Seriously, why would anyone down vote this?  Incredible.

Comment: @KDog, downvoting on Meta [means disagreement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites). It does not necessarily mean that the Q is invalid or so. That's why votes on Meta do not count into the user's reputation, actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this planned?

No.

The format actually supports this.  Someone could post a question e.g.

> Who should be President?

And provide answers like

> 1. Hillary Clinton.
> 2. Donald Trump.
> 3. Gary Johnson.
> 4. Jill Stein.
> 5. Evan McMullin.

However, if you try it, the question and/or answers are subject to being closed and deleted.  This particular question might be closed as opinion-based.

With a better question, the answers might be deleted as not real answers.  Answers are expected to exhibit research effort.  That's hard to do with competing poll options without ruining the polling aspect.

Anyway, my point is that this is not the direction that they want to go.  That would fit great on a discussion site (it's a common feature in forum software).  Maybe suggest it for chat.

Example Meta.SE question about [polls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112907/choice-of-tags-on-poll-related-topics).  Note how it says

> Hopefully these questions are on their way to deletion, but in the meantime we can't use the tag for something else.

That's the official position on polls.

They want questions with canonical answers.  People should be able to upvote good answers with which they disagree because the answer itself is informative.  In particular, people should feel comfortable upvoting competing answers that may come to different conclusions.  Opinion polls don't have that kind of answers, so they are unlikely to be encouraged.

Answer (score 7):

No, because exchanging opinions [is not the purpose of this website](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

> Politics Stack Exchange is for objective questions about governments, policies and political processes.
>
> It is not a place to advance opinions or debate, but rather for exchanging objective information about the policies, processes, and personalities that comprise the political arena. If you can't back it up, it's subjective.

How would knowing what our tiny and non-representative community thinks about a specific political issue help one to better understand governments, policies and political processes?

It might be on-topic to ask what the general public thinks about a specific political issue. But instead of making a poll among us, it would be far more constructive to ask for results from professional polling organizations which have results with far larger and far more controlled sample sizes.